# How to carry internal SSDs?

Tags: international-travel

I just got a new SSD; Kingston UV400, 120 GB. I often pull out 2.5 form factor drives and put it in a laptop or hot swap bay on a desktop in different locations. My questions are:
1. Are SSD prone to electrostatic damage like HDDs?
2. What are the best carry cases for internal SSDs, whose power and data contact pins are exposed?
3. Anything else to keep in mind while carrying SSDs which are not fitted to my laptop?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although it is a good travel related question it may be better answered at [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Newton Why? It's clearly a travel question.

Comment: I thought that SE would better address the electrostatic damage and pins specific cases. What we can recommend here is maybe stuff like keep it in something impact resistant and it may be searched while entering the US etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because part 1 is a question about electronics that has nothing to do with travel, part 2 is an off-topic product recommendation request and part 3 is, again, mostly an electronics question.

Comment: The Venn diagram for this question — with circles for "Hardware" and for "Travel" — overlap, and this question's in the overlapped area. I think it is entirely appropriate for either SE forum. It should stay open.

Comment: A resealable anti static bag is probably the best option. You can buy 50 for less then $/€/£10.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry, cannot follow that. Transporting SSDs safely during travel is not only an electronics question, it is also a question of cushioning/sturdy transport and transporting it in a way that avoids destruction by e.g. customs.

Comment: @ThorstenS. My rule of thumb for this kind of question is to ask myself which of the following two people would be able to answer the question: a computer hardware expert who never travels, or a traveller who knows nothing about computers. In this case, it's the hardware expert every time. The question is about computer hardware, and the travel aspect is entirely incidental.